# how to create list of given values in "a" usig python?

Tags: arrays, python-3.x, list, append

I have written a code which will give maximum value from all arrays.I want to store all these values in a single list but i am getting different lists of different values. how to create a single list of these values?

```
import numpy as np
import re
import gdal
import ogr
from osgeo import gdal_array
from gdalconst import *
import os
import osr
import shutil
import h5py
import subprocess
import operator
#np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
indir = '/home/vigna/Documents/LST_29_03'
directory=os.fsencode(indir)
e=1
for file in os.listdir(directory):    
    file1=os.fsdecode(file)    
    if '_Gadchiroli' in file1:
        b=str(e)+'_Gadchiroli.tif'
        #print(file1)
        gadchiroli=gdal.Open(b,GA_ReadOnly)
        gadchiroli_arry=gadchiroli.ReadAsArray()      
        a=np.amax(gadchiroli_arry)
        L=[]
        L.append(a)
        print(L)            
        e+=1
```

it gives result as shown in picture. i need all these values in single list.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oHrxi.png)

Comment: Please provide expected and actual output in text.

Comment: I have already added an image of actual output. I want output as [value1,value2...valuen]..all the values in single list. @ Akshay Nevrekar